# Using Newton Raphson's method to solve a non-linear boundary value problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

*(My specific question is at the end of the problem)*

Examine the boundary problem with a nonlinear right hand side $1+u^2(x)$
$$-u''(x) = 1+u^2(x) \quad \text{on} \quad 0 < x < 1 \quad \text{with} \quad u(0) = u(1) = 0$$
use 4 internal points $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, $x_4$. With $u_i = u(x_i)$ we use the finite difference approximation
$$u''(x_i) \approx \frac{-u(x_{i-1}) + 2u(x_i) - u(x_{i+1})}{h^2} = \frac{-u_{i-1} + 2u_i - u_{i+1}}{h^2}$$
where $h = \frac{1}{5} = 0.2$ and $u(x_0) = u_0 = u(x_5) = u_5 = 0$. 
Thus we obtain a non-linear system of equations.
$$
\frac{1}{0.4^2} 
\begin{bmatrix}
+2 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & +2 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & +2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & +2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_1 \\
u_2 \\
u_3 \\
u_4
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 + u_1^2 \\
1 + u_2^2 \\
1 + u_3^2 \\
1 + u_4^2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
To solve this non-linear system use methods from non linear problems, e.g. Newton's method: Use the Taylor approximation $(u+\phi)^2\approx u^2+2u\phi$. Start with an initial vector $\vec{u}_0$,  e.g.$\vec{u}_0=0$. Then use the iteration\newline
        \begin{align}
  \textbf{A}\cdot (\vec{u}_k + \vec{\phi})&=1+\vec{u}_k^2+2\vec{u}_k\cdot\vec{\phi}\\
  \textbf{A}\cdot (\vec{u}_k + \vec{\phi}) - 2\vec{u}_k\cdot\vec{\phi}&= 1+\vec{u}_k^2\\
  \textbf{A} \cdot (\vec{u}_k + \vec{\phi}) - \text{diag}(2\vec{u}_k)\cdot \phi &= 1 + \vec{u}_k^2\\
  \textbf{A}\cdot\phi + \textbf{A}\cdot\vec{u}_k- \text{diag}(2\vec{u}_k)\cdot\phi &= 1 + \vec{u}_k^2\\
  \textbf{A}\cdot\phi - \text{diag}(2\vec{u}_k)\cdot\phi &= 1 + \vec{u}_k^2-\textbf{A}\cdot\vec{u}_k\\
  (\textbf{A} - \text{diag}(2\vec{u}_k))\cdot \phi &= 1 + \vec{u}_k^2-\textbf{A}\cdot\vec{u}_k\tag{1}\\
  \vec{u}_{k+1} &=\vec{u}_k+\vec{\phi}\tag{2}
  \end{align}

**My question is:** how do we get from (1) to (2)?

Comment: (1) is a system of linear equations. What exactly do you want to know? How to solve systems of linear equations in general? Or which method is the best one for this special type of matrix (sparse band matrix)? Or if there is an explicit solution?

Comment: thank you for your answer @ReinhardMeier. Sorry I think I put too much for a rather focused question. I think solving a linear problem is clear for me as well as why you use Newton's method. My only question is how do you get at the end of the first of newton to the second one from (1) to (2) (the 2 last line of the question)

Comment: Solve (1) for $\phi$ and plug $\phi$ into (2)

Comment: indeed because $\phi$ is the unknown and is isolated in the last equation. Many thanks @ReinhardMeier